# In angularJS, having trouble instantiating main module

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

Every time I try to inject a dependency, I get this error:

Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module marbleApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngRoute due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngRoute' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

I started with this, and my code ran fine:

```
var app = angular.module("marbleApp", []);
```

But then when I try to inject a dependency like this, I get the above error...

```
var app = angular.module("marbleApp", ["ngRoute"]);
```

Any thoughts on why this could be happening?

Comment: Did you include `angular-route.js` in your HTML?

Comment: Wow, so stupid! Thank you, that solved it!

Answer (score 1):

remember that you have to check two things when you want to inject some dependencies:

First:

```
    var myModule = angular.module('myModule', [
        'myDependency',
        'mySecondDependency'
]);
```

Second:

```
    myModule.config(['myDependency', 'mySecondDependency',
        function(myDependency, mySecondDependency) {
    //here you can use injected stuff
    }
]);
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Did you install angular-route, to start with?

```
$ bower install angular-route
```

If you want to update your bower.json, too:

```
$ bower install angular-route --save
```

More, as the comment from @ddepablo suggests, double check you have it added in your `index.html` file:

```
<script src="angular-route.js">
```

(see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute)